# load commerce coupon

Tags: entities, commerce

I want to load coupons that have `commerce_discount_reference=4`. I find  that can load them by [commerce_coupon_load_multiple](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!commerce_coupon!commerce_coupon.module/function/commerce_coupon_load_multiple/DC) but I dont know how I add condition `commerce_discout_reference=4`.
maybe something like

```
  commerce_coupon_load_multiple(array(), array('commerce_discount_reference'=>4));
```

**what is correct way?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the perfect job for an [`EntityFieldQuery`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7):

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'commerce_coupon')
  ->fieldCondition('commerce_discount_reference', 'target_id', 4);

$results = $query->execute();
if (!empty($results['commerce_coupon'])) {
  $coupons = commerce_coupon_load_multiple(array_keys($results['commerce_coupon']));
}
```

Comment: always great :). tnx @Clive

Answer (score 1):

commerce_coupon_load_multiple function in turn uses entity_load function.

```
 if (empty($commerce_coupon_ids) && empty($conditions)) {
    return array();
  }

  return entity_load('commerce_coupon', $commerce_coupon_ids, $conditions, $reset);
```

As above documentation says

$conditions : An array of conditions to match against the {commerce_coupon} table.

Below is the commerce_coupon table schema

```
function commerce_coupon_schema() {
  $schema['commerce_coupon'] = array(
    'description' => 'The base table for coupons.',
    'fields' => array(
      'coupon_id' => array(
        'description' => 'The primary identifier for the coupon.',
        'type' => 'serial',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'uid' => array(
        'description' => 'An identifier for the user who owns this coupon',
        'type' => 'int',      
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => 0,          
      ),
      'type' => array(
        'description' => 'The type of this coupon.',
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => 32,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => '',
      ),
      'code' => array(
        'description' => 'The code of this coupon.',
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => 255,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => '',
      ),
      'bulk' => array(
        'description' => 'Whether or not this coupon code was generated in bulk.',
        'type' => 'int',
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => 0,
      ),
      'created' => array(
        'description' => 'The Unix timestamp when the coupon was created.',
        'type' => 'int',
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => 0,
      ),
      'status' => array(
        'description' => 'Whether or not this coupon is enabled.',
        'type' => 'int',
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => 0
      )
    ),
    'indexes' => array(
      'uid' => array('uid')        
    ),
    'primary key' => array('coupon_id'),
    'foreign keys' => array(
      'uid' => array(
        'table' => 'users',
        'column' => array('uid' => 'uid')
      ),        
    ),
    'unique keys' => array(
      'code' => array('code')
    )
  );

  return $schema;
}
```

As you see in above schema there exists no field called "commerce_discount_reference" which you can query on .. I believe "commerce_discount_reference" field is a custom field... So you need to use Entity Field Query as explained above by Clive...

Comment: yes, I also conclude this, thanks for your attention and your answer